# How to delete flask migration folder and table

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I want to fully delete the database and all the tables I have created. 
I tried everything.
table_instance.**table**.drop(engine)

I tried creating another project and reinstalling flask-migrate I still got No such revision '39408d6b248d' error and no such table: error when I use flask db upgrade.
Deleted the migration folder and used flask db init again it still gives no such revision.

The problem started when I used flask db migrate twice on the same table, then I got duplicate column error that I didn't know how to fix.

Answer (score 4):

You need to delete the `alembic_version` table that is in your database. Use your database admin tool to do it, or with a `drop table alembic_version;` SQL statement.

Comment: Please provide an example or provide a link for more information with this answer.

Comment: I'm showing you the SQL statement that you need to run. Isn't that an example?

Answer (score 1):

You can also delete the folder "migrations" in the root directory of your module, as well as the database.